# MySQL: why are there multiple root users?

Tags: mysql

On a clean install of MySQL (version: 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) running `SELECT User FROM mysql.user;` returns

```
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| root             |
| debian-sys-maint |
| root             |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can someone please tell me why there are 3 root users?

Comment: You should look at other columns which have other attributes. The different `root` entries probably have different attributes. Try for example, `select host, user from mysql.user;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` or `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;` and you will see..

One is for localhost, the other for 127.0.0.1 etc. - nothing to worry about.

Comment: isn't localhost the same as 127.0.0.1?

Comment: they should point to the same place but they aren't considered the same origin